# Reject google extension for no reason

Tags: google-chrome-extension

P.s. I using Google Translator

I have a google extension that analyzes csgo matches and makes a prediction. Once it has already been accepted (version 1.0.4). I did a global update, and the old version lost some of the functionality. But google does not accept the new update and there are no messages why:
[Usually the reason to the right of the "save draft" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlI9h.png)

I looked at all the corners of my account and there is no information anywhere why my extension was rejected.

I have local storage permission to store user settings and optional permission to load some hosts (user must confirm in order to use the program)
[I told about everything in the reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RinrN.png)

I looked at google's content policy and the only reason my extension could not be accepted was the gambling clause. But

1. My application is not a service for gambling, it only gives a prediction. Legally, these are different things, as I understand it in a couple of hours of Google
2. My extension was already accepted once, and in another version I did not change anything that could affect Google’s decision.
3. I believe that Google would write to me immediately about this.

Additional Information:

Name: BetBot

ID: dhddlpoaigekpmpmedehfiapchdcdgnl

manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "/js/jQuery.js", "/js/betsSelector.js" ]
        },

    "name": "BetBot",
    "version": "2.1.5",
    "description": "Бот для ставок CS:GO",
    "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' 'sha256-EzJN+hhYluDa3k6nd0M2pnhdS7ZRo4VqQ36+Fb/praY=' 'unsafe-eval' https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js; object-src 'self';",
    "permissions": [
      "storage" ],
    "optional_permissions": ["https://betscsgo.cc/", "http://bet-bot.ru.com/*", "https://www.hltv.org/*/*"],
    "homepage_url": "http://bet-bot.ru.com/",

     "browser_action": {
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
     },
    "icons": {  "16": "image/16x16.png",
                "32": "image/32x32.png",
                "64": "image/64x64.png",
                "128": "image/128x128.png"}
}
```

I can’t understand what to do to be accepted. I've been racking my brains for several days now.

Comment: The web store review is known to be nonsensical and mostly handled by automatic bots so keep appealing. The only thing I see in manifest.json is the leading `/` in `scripts` - the recent update in the web store has broken parsing of such paths so just remove the leading `/`.

Comment: No, it s doesn't work